# How to select a single line; the line number is known?

Tags: text-processing

<sub>This is probably a silly question but it's late at night, my brain has shut down.</sub>

I strive to assign the 'free' value of either command to a variable.

`cut -f` is cool but works(in this context) only over a single line.

`while read line; do echo $line; done < /tmp/file` and adding a counter is unacceptably complex.

I speak none of `sed`, `awk` nor `perl`, find `python`, `C` and friends an overkill for a simple script.

Simplest way to either chop the line or even the value?

```
[miro@katana ~]$ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        16077208     2392980     7992268      113892     5691960    13228756
Swap:       10485756           0    10485756

[miro@katana ~]$ vmstat 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0      0 7989240 518720 5173248    0    0     4    83   64  132 19  7 74  0  0
```

Expected output(not same with both commands for obvious reasons):

`7992268`

Comment: What is expected output? Which line/value do you want to fetch?

Comment: You can also get the content from `/proc/meminfo`, like this: `awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo` (I'm not sure if `vmstat` and `free` have different conditions for reporting free mem. But it seems actually both do the same, I've tested with `watch` command)